# Usage of Verb "Bridge"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, technical

I was wondering is it okay to use "bridge" as verb as follows:

> Throughout the article, we bridge A to B and concentrate on the most important application to C.

I treated A,B and C as something.

Comment: It is possible that in context (with A B and C filled in) I would understand what you meant. As  the example stands, I have no idea what "Bridge" is meant to mean.

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and common. The meaning is as one may expect, to connect/relate some(usually two) concepts, ideas, etc.

Take a look at these examples:

> If we attempt to **bridge** two concepts that are very far apart, more energy will be consumed (and lost) to achieve it.
>
> ...and by Doctors Without Borders It may be possible to **bridge** two ideas which are...